# GRASS r.volume Error

Tags: python, grass-7.0, volume

I am writing a Python script which uses a vector polygon outline to construct a raster map of a hypothetical 'mound'. Finally, the script will output the volume of this mound using `r.volume`.

The problem is that the `r.volume` calculation is resulting in an error. I can't get much info on the error but when I run the volume command in terminal I get no output other than:

```
:~> Floating point exception: 8
```

If I run the volume command using python I get:

```
grass.run_command("r.volume", input=rounded, clump='clumped')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Applications/GRASS-7.0.app/Contents/MacOS/etc/python/grass/script/core.py", line 395, in run_command
    return handle_errors(returncode, returncode, args, kwargs)
  File "/Applications/GRASS-7.0.app/Contents/MacOS/etc/python/grass/script/core.py", line 313, in handle_errors
    returncode=returncode)
CalledModuleError: Module run None ['r.volume', 'input=ditchpoly_area_comp_int_round', 'clump=clumped'] ended with error
Process ended with non-zero return code -8. See errors in the (error) output.
```

Below is the annotated python script that I used. If you want to reproduce the situation then I suggest drawing your own 'mound' shape and then inputting the name of this layer as the first python object and running the script.

```
import grass.script as grass
import os
import numpy as np

# name of your mound polygon shape layer
geooutline = "ditchpoly_area"

############ mound particulars ############

# distance from edge of polygon to foot of mound
erosion = float(-1.5)

# horizontal distance from mound base to mound peak
baseoffset = float(-3.00)

# height of mound
depth = float(3.30)

# rounding value for mound raster
rastrounding = float(0.1)

# names of mound objects
erooutline = geooutline + "_ero"
erooutlinerast = geooutline + "_ero_rast"
baseoutline = geooutline + "_base"
baseoutlinerast = geooutline + "_base_rast"
surface = geooutline + "_surface"
ditchbase = geooutline + "_ditchbase"
comp = geooutline + "_comp"
comp_int = geooutline + "_comp_int"
rounded = geooutline + "_comp_int_round"
ditchonly = geooutline + "_ditchonly"

############ grass commands ############ 

# set region
grass.run_command("g.region", flags="a", vectory=geooutline, nsres=1, ewres=1)

# create buffer outlines
grass.run_command("v.buffer", overwrite=True, input=geooutline, output=erooutline, distance=erosion)
grass.run_command("v.buffer", overwrite=True, input=erooutline, output=baseoutline, distance=baseoffset)

# prepare surface raster
grass.run_command("v.to.rast", overwrite=True, input=erooutline, output=erooutlinerast, use='cat')
formula = '"%s" = if(isnull("%s"), 0,null())' % (surface, erooutlinerast)
grass.raster.mapcalc(formula, overwrite=True)

# prepare ditch base
grass.run_command("v.to.rast", overwrite=True, input=baseoutline, output=baseoutlinerast, use='cat')
formula = '{0}" = if({1}" == 1,"{2}",null())' .format(ditchbase, baseoutlinerast, depth)
formula = formula.replace('"', '')
grass.raster.mapcalc(formula, overwrite=True)

# patch composite raster
compformula = surface + ',' + ditchbase
grass.run_command("r.patch", overwrite=True, input=compformula, output=comp)

# fill nulls interpolate ditch profile
grass.run_command("r.fillnulls", overwrite=True, input=comp, output=comp_int, method='rst')

# round values
formula = '"{0}" = float(round("{1}","{2}"))' .format(rounded, comp_int, rastrounding)
formula = formula.replace('"', '')
grass.raster.mapcalc(formula, overwrite=True)

# extract ditch
formula = '"{0}" = if("{1}" == 0,null(),"{2}")' .format(ditchonly, comp_int, rounded)
formula = formula.replace('"', '')
grass.raster.mapcalc(formula, overwrite=True)

# calculate volume
grass.run_command("r.volume", input=rounded, clump=erooutlinerast)

############  remove old files ############ 

#clear old
grass.run_command("g.remove", flags="f", type='all', pattern=geooutline + "_*")
```

Comment: If you test it try with a few different shapes and different offset and depth values - it's very temperamental

Comment: Just to add - I recently ran the script once resulting in a successful calculation, then when I ran it again (nothing changed) I got the error described above. Possible bug?